# how to spread small image file in background and it should scroll with other elements

Tags: html, css, image, tags

this is my css code the image file (.png) 40*40px and it is a small file i want to spread it all over the body (background).
i did with 'fixed' thing it worked, but when i scroll it doesn't move with other elements

```
body{
background:url('short.png') fixed;
}
```

then i tried with repeat-x or repeat-y but i don't know how to implement both thing in body tag

```
body{
background:url('short.png') repeat-x;
}
```

remember my image file is 40* 40px i want to apply everywhere and when i scroll it should move with other tags which is opposite to 'fixed' thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background:url('short.png') 0 0 repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work:

```
   body{
   background-image:url('short.png')
   background-repeat: Repeat;  
   background-attachment:fixed;
   }
```